# JS Map file debugging in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, source-maps

is there a way how to debug source maps in chrome? At least to see where is what mapped?

My problem is that I am remapping ts generated file (using source-maps), for whatever reason, does not matter. When I remap them and use console.log or console.error the console correctly shows the line where the console.log or console.error was executed and I can even navigate to the line in the original ts source file. But when I try to set a break point in the .js file on the same line where the console.log is located the break point is set incorrectly to "previous" line (or other file, if there is no any statement in the .ts file)

So the question is, is there a way to tell to chrome to show me mapped relations for js and ts files? If no, is there any other tool, ideally friendly, where I can click on statement and see were is it mapped to? I am lazy to write one, especially in this case I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

EDIT:

In between I have found this:
http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/#

and this:
https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer

I could not find anything because I was asking google in a wrong way.

EDIT2:

My bundled and remapped files seems to be ok.

It seems to be a bug in chrome debuger itself. Because when I place a break point directly to the typescript file it stops correctly.

So it seems to me the chrome incorrectly maps only breakpoints set in the original (bundled) js file what is actually bundle of compiled typescipt files accompanied with remapped .js.map files to the .js.map bundle.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128859/how-can-i-take-a-minified-javascript-stack-trace-and-run-it-against-a-source-map thats about as close as I could get for you

Comment: or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154874/can-i-re-construct-the-original-javascript-source-file-from-a-minified-version-a?rq=1

Comment: By the way, can you tell me what is the question related to? I really don't understand your reaction. Thast at a. and at b, I don't more understand the reason for downvote...

Comment: It seems to be a bug in chrome.

Comment: [Source Maps in DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps#source_maps_in_devtools_sources_panel)